# Should I write a component or a module? (or both?)

Tags: php, joomla, components, module

I'm trying to write a slideshow for joomla. Specifically one that will be placed next to an article (no necessarily associated with the article though). Should i write a component, or a module? OR should I write a component that is placed in the page using a module (like the com_banner and mod_banner stuff in the joomla basic installation).

I know I am reinventing the wheel, but I really want to learn about joomla modding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a module. You can assign modules to any menu items.

Modules will appear on that page and "sub-pages". For example, if you assign a module to a menu item that points to a "Article blog layout", then it will appear on that page and the articles linked from it.

If you only want one specific article, or any page without a specific menu item, create a new menu called "hidden menu" and make a menu item in it. Menus don't appear unless you publish the menu module.

By the way, there are many slideshow components for Joomla already out there - Photoslide from [gavick.com](http://www.gavick.com/downloads-area/list/download-5-free-downloads.html) is pretty good, and free.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to associate the slideshow to a specific article i think you should write a component, because in this way you have more control on the article and you can manage its structure and its layout.

Comment: Clarified my question a bit :)

It can, but does not have to. I should be able to place the same slideshow next to different articles.

If i were to go this way (where i would write a component), should I use the com_content component as a starting point?